# Can't quite understand this simple pseudo random generator from Schneier in 1992

Tags: c, random, cryptography, xor, prng

Schneier posts at https://www.schneier.com/paper-pseudorandom-sequence.html:

```
int VERYRANDOM()  {
    static unsigned long regA, regB, regC;
    /*regA, regB, and regC should be initialized with some random value.*/
    regA = ((((regA>>31)^(regA>>6)^(regA>>4)^(regA>>2)^(regA<<1)^regA)
        & 0x00000001)<<31) | (regA>>1);
    regB = ((((regB>>30)^(regB>>2)) & 0x00000001)<<30) | (regB>>1);
    regC = ((((regC>>28)^(regC>>1)) & 0x00000001)<<28) | (regC>>1);
    /*regB is a 31-bit LFSR.  regC is a 29-bit LFSR.*/
    /*Both feedback sequences are chosen to be maximum length.*/
    return ((regA & regB) | (!regA & regC)) & 0x00000001;
    /*Above is equivalant to:  if A then return B else return C.*/
    /* Variants:  return ((regA & regB) | (regA & regC) | (regB & regC)) &
    0x00000001; Above variant returns the majority of A, B, and C.
    return (regA ^ regB ^ regC) & 0x00000001;
    Above variant returns the XOR of A, B, and C.  */
}
```

And finished by warning against blindly choosing a different feedback sequence. To avoid venturing down such blind alleys I've read up on LFSR and the polynomials that define them.

One place, http://www.newwaveinstruments.com/resources/articles/m_sequence_linear_feedback_shift_register_lfsr.htm is kind enough to list maximal length polynomials against however many taps (which is abridged for clarity as more taps become an option). For the 32 bit LFSR I don't understand where Schneier is getting his polynomial from:

```
    regA = ((((regA>>31)^(regA>>6)^(regA>>4)^(regA>>2)^(regA<<1)^regA)
        & 0x00000001)<<31) | (regA>>1);
```

According to the wikipedia on LFSR the equivalent polynomial would be:

```
    //Fibonacci x^1         x^26      x^28     x^30      x^31     x^32      
    regA = ((((regA>>31)^(regA>>6)^(regA>>4)^(regA>>2)^(regA<<1)^regA)
        & 0x00000001)<<31) | (regA>>1);
```

which isn't on the table:

> [32, 31, 30, 29, 5, 1]
>   [32, 31, 30, 28, 27, 3]
>   [32, 31, 30, 28, 26, 13]
>   [32, 31, 30, 28, 23, 21]
>   [32, 31, 30, 28, 23, 18]
>   [32, 31, 30, 28, 20, 15]
>   [32, 31, 30, 28, 20, 3]
>   [32, 31, 30, 28, 19, 2]
>   [32, 31, 30, 28, 19, 1]
>   [32, 31, 30, 28, 17, 9]
>   [32, 31, 30, 28, 17, 4]
>   [32, 31, 30, 28, 17, 3]
>   [32, 31, 30, 28, 15, 5]
>   [32, 31, 30, 28, 14, 2]
>   [32, 31, 30, 28, 12, 9]
>   [32, 31, 30, 28, 10, 7]
>   [32, 31, 30, 27, 26, 9]

I don't want to misunderstand anything while learning the basics of crypto so why don't I get this? Before attempting to apply the terminology from Wikipedia's example I had *diagnosed* the polynomial as:

```
    //                      25      27          29      30      31
    regA = ((((regA>>31)^(regA>>6)^(regA>>4)^(regA>>2)^(regA<<1)^regA)
        & 0x00000001)<<31) | (regA>>1);
```

But it is XOR'ing the (leftmost) MSbit which goes unaccounted for then, also, odd number of taps is a sure sign I was wrong.

The wikipedia translating of polynomials is:

```
    /* taps: 16 14 13 11; feedback polynomial: x^16 + x^14 + x^13 + x^11 + 1 */
    bit  = ((lfsr >> 0) ^ (lfsr >> 2) ^ (lfsr >> 3) ^ (lfsr >> 5) ) & 1;
```

I guess wikipedia and newwaveinstruments use different terminology, but if I can't decipher what it is I can forget about understanding cryptography.

Comment: For now I can only vote up, but if you want to understand cryptography, then you need first to understand that this isn't encryption. Never forget to add language tags either; if you think your question can do without them: use http://crypto.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: I can't answer anything about your question, but I think there's a typo in the code (the typo is in Schneier's article).  I believe that the code `((((regA>>31)^(regA>>6)^(regA>>4)^(regA>>2)^(regA<<1)^regA)` should be `((((regA>>31)^(regA>>6)^(regA>>4)^(regA>>2)^(regA>>1)^regA)`.  That is, the last shift operation should be a right shift instead of a left shift.

Comment: Michael Burr is right. This is just a misprint. Compare it to RANDOM in the same post by Schneier. Secondly, the LFSR does NOT have period 2^32 - 1. Simply assign regA to any non-zero value and loop until you get the same value. The period will be 0x5553EAAA = 1,431,562,922. Never been impressive by Schneier's work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. This code really sucks.

When seeded with a value of 1, the first LFSR repeats itself after just 107,359,437 iterations. This falls far short of the 4 billion iterations you would get with a maximal length 32-bit LFSR. With other seed values, the results could be even worse.

In fact, since the other two LFSRs don't include bit 0 in the feedback loop, seeding either of these with a value of 1 would result in them generating an infinite sequence of zeros straight away.

Frankly I'm astounded that someone with Schneier's credentials could possibly come up with something as rubbish as this.

In any case, LFSRs are utterly useless for crypto applications. ARCFOUR includes a simple pseudo-random generator that works *much* better than Shneier's effort, and probably a lot faster too. But don't go inventing your own cryptography methods. There's really no need :-)

Comment: I put in some other seed and got the same repeat period. I suppose cramming code onto one line like that could be considered to _suck_ albeit less so if it could be considered out-of-sight out-of-mind, as it is so badly broken, yep, that's rubbish alright. I won't debate its crypto efficacy, it serves as an obfuscator in cases where proper security is too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correct version of [32, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0] (Schneier's notation from table 16.2 in Applied Cryptography, 2nd Edition).

```
#include <cstdio>

// regA should be initialized with some random n0n-zero value.
static unsigned long regA;

int rand_bit()
{
    int length = 32;
    regA = (((
          (regA >> 7)
        ^ (regA >> 5)
        ^ (regA >> 3)
        ^ (regA >> 2)
        ^ (regA >> 1)
        ^ (regA >> 0))
        & 0x00000001)
        << (length - 1))
        | (regA >> 1);
    return regA & 0x00000001;
}

int main()
{
    const unsigned long start = 0x00000001;
    regA = start;
    for (unsigned long c = 1; ; ++c)
    {
        int bit = rand_bit();
        //printf("%d\n", bit);

        if (regA == start)
        {
            printf("%#010x\n", c);

            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to do the [32, 31, 30, 29, 5, 1] from http://www.newwaveinstruments.com/resources/articles/m_sequence_linear_feedback_shift_register_lfsr/32stages.txt, you would use the following version of rand_bit. Notice, using Schneier's notation this would be [32, 31, 30, 29, 5, 1, 0].

```
int rand_bit()
{
    int length = 32;
    regA = (((
          (regA >> 31)
        ^ (regA >> 30)
        ^ (regA >> 29)
        ^ (regA >> 5)
        ^ (regA >> 1)
        ^ (regA >> 0))
        & 0x00000001)
        << (length - 1))
        | (regA >> 1);
    return regA & 0x00000001;
}
```